# Move the circle along the pipe

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, move, raycasting

the circle is slightly larger than the pipe and I want to make it move along it so that it changes its angle depending on the rotation of the pipe. That is, in fact, so that the circle is always inside the pipe. But I have no idea how to do it

I tried to release 4 beams from the circle directed at the pipe, but again I have no idea what to do next

[image: img]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's quite enough information right now to help you with a script for this, since you haven't included any coding attempts. But using raycasts (as it sounds like you tried) could be a promising approach. Consider what information you get back when you hit the pipe with a raycast - particularly, consider how you can use the normal vector to orient the circle, and how you can use the hit point to determine where to position the circle. Try writing a script to use that information, and if you run into specific issues you can bring that script here for help.

Comment: yes you need to provide more information. What would make more sense to me is to achieve the central curve that describes the pipe. Then at any given point of the pipe you would have the direction the pipe is facing to so to apply it to the circle.